# When to use strategy or facade?

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

So me and my group is working on this real estate program (school assignment), we are troubled if we used misused Strategy pattern, and should use Facade instead. I am writing codes for CRUD of database, I used Strategy pattern to call those CRUD methods (add,delete,update) from the jform. We are still starting to learn different design patterns, so we would like to as help if this is a correct implementation.

This is my code for Strategy Pattern

```
public interface methods {
    public void doOperation(int id, String type, int area, String address, String listingStatus);
}

public class methodUse {
    private methods method;

    public methodUse(methods method) {
        this.method = method;
    }
    
    public void executeMethod(int id, String type, int area, String address, String listingStatus){
         method.doOperation(id, type, area, address, listingStatus);
    }
}

public class methodUpdate implements methods{
    private SystemAdmin systemAdmin = new SystemAdmin();

    @Override
    public void doOperation(int id, String type, int area, String address, String listingStatus) {
        systemAdmin.updatePropertyListing(id, listingStatus);
    
    }
}

public class methodDelete implements methods{
   private SystemAdmin systemAdmin = new SystemAdmin();


    @Override
    public void doOperation(int id, String type, int area, String address, String listingStatus) {
      systemAdmin.deleteListing(id);
    }
}

public class methodAdd implements methods{
    private SystemAdmin systemAdmin = new SystemAdmin();

    @Override
    public void doOperation(int id, String type, int area, String address, String listingStatus) {
        systemAdmin.addListing(id, type, area, address, listingStatus);
    }
    
}
```

The classes are called on the jform every time the specific button is clicked, ex. add button executes strategy add.

I would like to ask you all if what we did was the right implementation of Strategy pattern.

Comment: Design patterns are not _goals_, they are _shorthand for common designs_. Is this project a school assignment or for real-world use?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- just a school assignment, we are trying to apply what we learnt so far by creating this real estate system

Comment: The Strategy and Facade patterns are not alternatives to each other.  It is plausible that a program might use both.  Nor is there generally a single correct answer to how to design a program or which design patterns might be useful in it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ohh, I see, so is it safe to say is that it is the one who is coding the program who would decide how a certain design pattern would be useful for their program?

Comment: With that said, (1) your code looks more like an implementation of the Command pattern than of the Strategy pattern; (2) I don't see what is supposed to be gained by all that.  You've written fifty-ish lines of code just to avoid using class `SystemAdmin` directly?

Comment: @Kaa, yes, more or less.  One uses design patterns to serve a particular purpose, not just for the sake of using them.  That does not mean that multiple people can't all have input on design decisions, but implementing more patterns does not magically make your program better, and there are usually different approaches that use different suites of patterns.

Comment: Good rule of thumb: don't even *THINK* about using "design patterns" until you're ready to *SIMPLIFY* your design.  You're putting the horse before the cart ... and your code is unnecessarily complex as a result...

Comment: Thank you, to clarify those are not written in the same .java file, I wrote them on different .java because that is what is taught or rather demonstrated to us. I will check on the command pattern that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: When should I use a "Strategy" pattern?

> https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy
>
> Use the Strategy pattern when you want to use different variants of an
> algorithm within an object and be able to switch from one algorithm to
> another during runtime.

So in this case, you're not "wrong" to choose a "Strategy" pattern

Q: [Is] what we did was the right implementation of Strategy pattern?

> - Declare the strategy interface common to all variants of the algorithm.
> - One by one, extract all algorithms into their own classes. They should all implement the strategy interface.

So yes, you have implemented it correctly.

Q: So what about "Facade"?

As John Bollinger correctly said:

> The Strategy and Facade patterns are not alternatives to each other. It
> is plausible that a program might use both. Nor is there generally a
> single correct answer to how to design a program or which design
> patterns might be useful in it.

Comment: "So in this case, you're not "wrong" to choose a "Strategy" pattern" - it's true that there is some subjectivity about *intentions* in patterns. But since CRUD are operations (as opposed to algorithms), I fail to see the need to change them at runtime - each operation does a semantically different thing. Strategy would make sense to determine how a customer is paying for a transaction (e.g. Credit card vs Gift card). It's the same operation, but different algorithm, and the customer decides at run time.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to understand the difference between structural vs behavioural patter.

**Structural pattern (Facade):**
Structural patterns are concerned with how classes and objects are composed to form larger structures. You can remember it as **compile time** decisions.

Eg: Your use case will come under facade pattern as the button are fixed and your focus is mostly defining the class structure; you can call it as early binding.

**Behavioural pattern (Strategy):**
Behavioural patterns are concerted with algorithms and the assignment of responsibilities between objects. You can remember it as **run time** decisions.

Eg: Payment gateway, there are many way of doing payment viz internet banking, card, UPI etc. Based on the option user choose on runtime, the top level interface is delegating to corresponding implementation.

**Note:** Designing patterns is all about precision based on use case and there is no right or wrong answers.